# Can't move mouse cursor up on Qemu

Tags: ubuntu, qemu

I recently migrated an Ubuntu image from VirtualBox (dowloaded from https://practicalbinaryanalysis.com/) to qcow2 and run it under Qemu. It boots up smoothly, supports network and higher resolutions, but the mouse works only in 3/4, meaning I can move it to the left, right and down, but it doesn't go up...
With other OSes, when I had mouse problems I could solve it, by adding a tablet device. Here, it behaves more or less the same, no matter what input device it is provided with.

My VM configuration:
https://pastebin.com/xKEHRUX1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the issue I needed to install spice-vdagent package on a guest machine from apt (https://packages.debian.org/pl/sid/spice-vdagent).

After executing

```
sudo apt install spice-vdagent && reboot
```

everything is working well and mouse cursor is synchronized correctly.